# Swift CoreData - Is it possible to pull data from a related entity in the fetchRequest?

Tags: swift, select, core-data

Update: Answered my question by taking advantage of a to-one relationship going the reversed way. Would love to know if there is a way to expand the selection of the fetchRequest to include other entities.

---

My current fetch request in `Swift` grabs from the main table, lets call it `mainTable`, and filters it using an in-between entity, let's call it `betweenTable`, based on a single object in my third entity, `thirdTable`. This works. Here's how it's set up.

```
fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Screen>(entity: mainTable.entity(),
                                            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \mainTable.displayName, ascending: true)],
                                            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "betweenTable.thirdTable CONTAINS[cd] %@", selectedThirdItem))
```

This fetch is based on a condition on the `betweenEntity` table (a to-many relationship) based on a value on the `thirdTable` (a to-one relationship). I want to grab a value from the `betweenEntity` table to use in my list (where the results from this fetch are shown) BUT when I try to index into the `between` table in the list my build times out. I was hoping there was a way to expand the values selected in the fetch request to include more than just the `mainTable` entity. For example `select mainTable.value, betweenTable.value from ... where...`

Can't find any information on this online and was hoping it was possible.

Thanks for any help.

More Information:

`mainTable` ->> `betweenTable` is a to-many relationship.
`mainTable` -> `thirdTable` is a to-one relationship but to-many reversed.

My main fetch request is for a list that I created as my previous version did live-update and needed to be forced.

Within the list I tried to get the value needed with a `mainTable.betweenTable.first(where: ...` type expression but then I couldn't build it so I hoped I could add a value in the `select` for the fetch request. Error: `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Comment: Just do mainTable.betweenValue.value in your Swift code, core data handles this for you so the related objects exists in memory or is loaded automatically when you access them

Comment: I might try that... that said I did something similar before and the app wouldn't build. I added a bit more information to the question :)

Comment: I am talking about accessing the result of the fetch request and not modifying the request itself.

Comment: Won't mainTable.betweenValues give me a Set of Entities... rather than the one I filtered down by in the fetchRequest?

Comment: It wasn’t clear before that this was a to-many relationship. First you talked about accessing values but now it seems to be about filtering. Maybe you could rewrite the question so it becomes clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had started looking into the `NSFetchRequest.IncludesSubentities` property but couldn't find anything helpful.

I ended up fixing this by switching my query to grab from the `betweenTable` entity and then follow the to-one relationship back to the `mainTable` for display purposes. This way I can display values from both tables. The predicate became a simple `predicate: NSPredicate(format: "thirdTable == %@", selectedThirdItem)`